# Matlab histcounts show values on x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, histogram, axis

I want to draw a histogram, using `plot(histcounts(X,edges))`.
It works fine, except that on the x-axis, the number of the bin is displayed, not the actual value the bin refers to.

To make a bit clearer what I mean, I append two plots. Both display the same data, but for the first one, I used `plot(histcounts(X,edges))` and for the second `hist(X,edges)`. The plot for which I used hist shows the x-axis the way I want it to look like, with the value the bin refers to. I would like the `plot(histcount(...)` to have the same x-axis, instead of showing the bin number.

Histogram using `plot(histcounts)`:

[image: histogram using plot(histcounts)]

Histogram using `hist`:
[image: histogram using hist]

How can I change the x-axis to show this value instead of the bin number?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: why dont you use `histogram`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the edges, you can get the centres using

```
centres = edges(1:end-1)+ diff(edges)/2;
```

then the plot can be

```
plot(centres, histcounts(X,edges));
```

If you do not need to specify the edges you can get them using

```
[h_counts, edges] = histcounts(X);
```